# Look up (and Replace) values in data frame based on lookup table (with more than one column)

Tags: r

UPDATE Below

:Original

I'm trying to find the most elegant (simple and concise) way of replacing the value of certain columns based on matching two columns from another data frame.

Here is the table with the columns I wish to replace (based on what values they contain).

```
> cost.table
  Identifier Phase.0.Difficulty Phase.1.Complexity Phase.2.Complexity Phase.3.Complexity Phase.4.Complexity Phase.5.Complexity
1        FS1                Low                Low                Low             Medium             Medium               High
2        FS2               High               High               High             Medium             Medium             Medium
3        FS3               High                Low                Low               High               High               High
4        FS4               High             Medium             Medium             Medium             Medium             Medium
5        FS5               High             Medium             Medium               High             Medium             Medium
  Phase.6.Complexity Transaction.Feasibility Approach
1               High                  Medium        B
2             Medium                  Medium        I
3               High                  Medium        B
4             Medium                  Medium        I
5             Medium                  Medium        B
```

And here are the lookup tables that I wish to use to find the correct replacement value.

```
> cost.approach.difficulty
  Approach Difficulty   Phase 0  Phase 1  Phase 2   Phase 3  Phase 4  Phase 5  Phase 6
1        B       High 18102.778 29481.67 29481.67 11822.222 30737.78 21634.67 12768.00
2        B        Low  3860.694 15978.47 11175.69  7448.000 12768.00 11467.56 11467.56
3        B     Medium  5323.694 24974.44 15184.17  9221.333 15368.89 12768.00 12768.00
4        I       High 18102.778 74184.44 29481.67 44747.111 69160.00 45249.56 32245.11
5        I        Low  3860.694 26008.89 11175.69 16551.111 35910.00 16876.22 14275.33
6        I     Medium  5323.694 41156.11 15184.17 22373.556 44776.67 23378.44 16876.22
7       RV       High 18102.778 28373.33 29481.67 44747.111 69160.00 45249.56 32245.11
8       RV        Low  3860.694 14870.14 11175.69 16551.111 44776.67 16876.22 14275.33
9       RV     Medium  5323.694 22757.78 15184.17 22373.556 44776.67 23378.44 16876.22
```

I'm trying to find a simple solution to look up the corresponding value in the cost.approach.difficulty table for 'Approach' and 'Difficulty'.

So for example, in the cost.table, I would like to have the first row, column Phase.0.Difficulty, be replaced with 3860.694 (because it is a 'B' approach and low difficulty.

Does anyone have an elegant, simple solution to looking up a value based on two (or more columns) and replacing the value along multiple columns?

Thank you,

Andrew

UPDATE -

There are two proposed answers related to using merge.  My goal is to find a more succinct, concise, and elegant solution.  Here is the best that I've come up with so far:

```
cost.approach.difficulty$Phase.0[match(paste(cost.table$Approach, cost.table$Phase.0.Difficulty), paste(cost.approach.difficulty$Approach, cost.approach.difficulty$Difficulty))]
```

The problem with this solution is that I'd need to know the column names ahead of time and still seems like a hack.  Anyone have a more concise solution?

Comment: it's always a bad idea to have column names with blanks as in `cost.approach.difficulty`. Could they be fixed with `colnames(cost.approach.difficulty) <- make.names( colnames(cost.approach.difficulty) )`?

Comment: Beasterfield, I'm not really worried about the names (this is just an example)--the real question is how do you go through a number of columns, by row, and replace the value based on a lookup of two columns from another data frame.

Comment: You really should be worried about the names. If nothing else, having strangely formatted example data (names or otherwise) makes it that much more difficult for someone here to use that example data to help answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want this to work for a variable number of columns, I suggests reshaping your cost table and your lookup table(s) into a more standardized format.

First, it would have been easier to answer this question if you had given your data in a reproducible format:

```
# Create the example data
cost.table <- data.frame(
  "Identifier" = c("FS1", "FS2",  "FS3",  "FS4",  "FS5"),
  "Phase.0.Difficulty" = c("Low", "High", "High", "High", "High"),
  "Phase.1.Complexity" = c("Low", "High", "Low", "Medium", "Medium"),
  "Phase.2.Complexity" = c("Low", "High", "Low", "Medium", "Medium"),
  "Phase.3.Complexity" = c("Medium", "Medium", "High", "Medium", "High"),
  "Phase.4.Complexity" = c("Medium", "Medium", "High", "Medium", "Medium"),
  "Phase.5.Complexity" = c("High", "Medium", "High", "Medium", "Medium"),
  "Phase.6.Complexity" = c("High", "Medium", "High", "Medium", "Medium"),
  "Transaction.Feasibility" = c("Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium"),
  "Approach" = c("B", "I", "B", "I", "B"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cost.approach.difficulty <- data.frame(
  "Approach" = c("B", "B", "B", "I", "I", "I", "RV", "RV", "RV"),
  "Difficulty" = c("High", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Medium"),
  "Phase.0" = c(18102.778, 3860.694, 5323.694, 18102.778, 3860.694, 5323.694, 18102.778, 3860.694, 5323.694),
  "Phase.1" = c(29481.67,15978.47, 24974.44, 74184.44, 26008.89, 41156.11, 28373.33, 14870.14, 22757.78),
  "Phase.2" = c(29481.67, 11175.69, 15184.17, 29481.67, 11175.69, 15184.17, 29481.67, 11175.69, 15184.17),
  "Phase.3" = c(11822.222, 7448, 9221.333, 44747.111, 16551.111, 22373.556, 44747.111, 16551.111, 22373.556),
  "Phase.4" = c(30737.78, 12768, 15368.89, 69160, 35910, 44776.67, 69160, 44776.67, 44776.67),
  "Phase.5" = c(21634.67, 11467.56, 12768, 45249.56, 16876.22, 23378.44, 45249.56, 16876.22, 23378.44),
  "Phase.6" = c(12768, 11467.56, 12768, 32245.11, 14275.33, 16876.22, 32245.11, 14275.33, 16876.22),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Once I had recreated your example data, I used the `melt.data.frame` function from the `reshape2` package:

```
# Reshape the data
require(reshape2)

cost.table <- melt(cost.table, id.vars = c("Identifier", "Approach"), 
  value.name = "Size")
cost.table$Phase <- gsub("(\\w+\\.\\d+)\\.(\\w+)", "\\1", 
  as.character(cost.table$variable), perl = TRUE)
cost.table$Type <- gsub("(\\w+\\.\\d+)\\.(\\w+)", "\\2", 
  as.character(cost.table$variable), perl = TRUE)

head(cost.table)

  Identifier Approach           variable Size   Phase       Type
1        FS1        B Phase.0.Difficulty  Low Phase.0 Difficulty
2        FS2        I Phase.0.Difficulty High Phase.0 Difficulty
3        FS3        B Phase.0.Difficulty High Phase.0 Difficulty
4        FS4        I Phase.0.Difficulty High Phase.0 Difficulty
5        FS5        B Phase.0.Difficulty High Phase.0 Difficulty
6        FS1        B Phase.1.Complexity  Low Phase.1 Complexity

cost.approach.difficulty <- melt(cost.approach.difficulty, 
  id.vars = c("Difficulty", "Approach"), variable.name = "Phase")
cost.approach.difficulty$Phase <- as.character(cost.approach.difficulty$Phase)
cost.approach.difficulty$Type <- "Difficulty"
colnames(cost.approach.difficulty)[
  colnames(cost.approach.difficulty) == "Difficulty"] <- "Size"

head(cost.approach.difficulty)

    Size Approach   Phase     value       Type
1   High        B Phase.0 18102.778 Difficulty
2    Low        B Phase.0  3860.694 Difficulty
3 Medium        B Phase.0  5323.694 Difficulty
4   High        I Phase.0 18102.778 Difficulty
5    Low        I Phase.0  3860.694 Difficulty
6 Medium        I Phase.0  5323.694 Difficulty
```

Once the two tables are in a standardized format, you can call `merge`:

```
cost.table.filled <- merge(cost.table, cost.approach.difficulty, 
  by = c("Approach", "Size", "Phase", "Type"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
```

Then, if you didn't look up the values for certain columns, you can re-insert the original values (otherwise you end up with a bunch of NAs):

```
cost.table.filled$value[is.na(cost.table.filled$value)] <- 
  cost.table.filled$Size[is.na(cost.table.filled$value)]
```

Then you can `dcast` the thing back into the original format:

```
cost.table.final <- dcast(cost.table.filled, Identifier + Approach ~ Phase + Type)

head(cost.table.final)

  Identifier Approach Phase.0_Difficulty Phase.1_Complexity Phase.2_Complexity Phase.3_Complexity Phase.4_Complexity Phase.5_Complexity Phase.6_Complexity Transaction.Feasibility_Transaction.Feasibility
1        FS1        B           3860.694                Low                Low             Medium             Medium               High               High                                          Medium
2        FS2        I          18102.778               High               High             Medium             Medium             Medium             Medium                                          Medium
3        FS3        B          18102.778                Low                Low               High               High               High               High                                          Medium
4        FS4        I          18102.778             Medium             Medium             Medium             Medium             Medium             Medium                                          Medium
5        FS5        B          18102.778             Medium             Medium               High             Medium             Medium             Medium                                          Medium
```

To replace all columns, I would `melt` each lookup table and then `cbind` them all together into a single lookup table. That way, you only have to call `merge` once and you don't have to worry about replacing NAs.

Comment: Schaun, this is A solution but very messy and not very concise.  I've found it cleaner to simply use paste and match, but I am so surprised that there is no native support for using lookup tables.  Using reshape (which is unnecessary, in my opinion) and merging the data frames is unnecessarily complex.  I'll post a simple example using match, but I was really hoping someone out there knew a better (read, concise and elegant) method.

Comment: Here is the cleanest solution that I've found so far. cost.approach.difficulty$Phase.0[match(paste(cost.table$Approach, cost.table$Phase.0.Difficulty), paste(cost.approach.difficulty$Approach, cost.approach.difficulty$Difficulty))]

Comment: Inelegant data organization often necessitates inelegant data manipulation. The way you've organized your data makes it hard to create a concise and extensible approach: your lookup table keeps information about type, size, and phase in different places, but your cost.table combines type and phase together. A "one column, one metric" organization reduces the total amount of code needed to manipulate the data. With the structure you have, your concise solution requires you to know all column names beforehand, which means even that isn't really a clean solution.

Comment: SchaunW, thank you for the constructive criticism of the demo data! In the meantime, the most elegant solution appears to be paste and match.

Comment: I wasn't so much criticizing your demo data as I was trying to explain why a more elegant solution than what you've already found may not be obtainable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `merge` should do the trick:

```
cost.table <- merge(
  x = cost.table,
  y = cost.approach.difficulty[c("Approach", "Difficulty", "Phase.0")],
  by.x = c("Phase.0.Difficulty", "Approach"),
  by.y = c("Difficulty", "Approach"), sort = FALSE
)
cost.table$Phase.0.Difficulty <- NULL
names(cost.table)[names(cost.table) == "Phase.0"] <- "Phase.0.Difficulty"

cost.table
  Approach Identifier Phase.1.Complexity Phase.2.Complexity Phase.3.Complexity Phase.4.Complexity Phase.5.Complexity Phase.6.Complexity Transaction.Feasibility Phase.0.Difficulty
1        B        FS1                Low                Low             Medium             Medium               High               High                  Medium           3860.694
2        I        FS2               High               High             Medium             Medium             Medium             Medium                  Medium          18102.778
3        I        FS4             Medium             Medium             Medium             Medium             Medium             Medium                  Medium          18102.778
4        B        FS3                Low                Low               High               High               High               High                  Medium          18102.778
5        B        FS5             Medium             Medium               High             Medium             Medium             Medium                  Medium          18102.778
```

Comment: Beasterfield, that is one approach but can be unwieldy if there are many columns.  In this case, each "phase.x.." column needs to be replaced with the lookup value, not just one column.  I was hoping for a method of using 'match' to find the corresponding value for each phase.x (across all columns).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer appears to be to:

- Combine lookup columns using paste
- Use match to find the row number from the lookup table

The code below accomplishes the multiple column lookup with one line.

```
    cost.approach.difficulty$Phase.0[match(paste(cost.table$Approach, 
cost.table$Phase.0.Difficulty), paste(cost.approach.difficulty$Approach, 
cost.approach.difficulty$Difficulty))]
```

To cycle through multiple columns, a for loop works fine.

Unfortunately, I was hoping for a native solution that perhaps took a vector of columns and combined them for the lookup, but I haven't found it yet.  I'll be checking additional packages to see if such a function exists.